MongoDB rest api with spring boot, findById() Type question
im learning how to make a rest api with java Spring and combining it with mongoDB. Im trying to make a simple CRUD with a customer object. For now it is working great, but im having issues with the findById() Method. Since mongoDB creates an _id for me which is a String, how do i use the built in method findById() since it is requiring a long as a parameter. Here is my code for my method.
public void updateCustomer(Customer customer) {
        System.out.println(customer.getId());
        Customer foundObject = customerRepository.findById(customer.getId())
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Customer not found"));
        foundObject.setFirstName(customer.getFirstName());
        foundObject.setLastName(customer.getLastName());
        foundObject.setEmail(customer.getEmail());
        foundObject.setPhone(customer.getPhone());
        foundObject.setPassword(customer.getPassword());
        foundObject.setAddress(customer.getAddress());
        customerRepository.save(foundObject);
    }

Here is the code for my repository.
package com.test.test.repository;

import com.test.test.model.Customer;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query;

import java.util.Optional;

public interface CustomerRepository extends MongoRepository<Customer, Long> {
    @Query("{'firstName': ?0}")
    Optional<Customer> findByFirstName(String name);
}

I cant parse it to a Long since the ID is containing letters. Do i make my own findById() Method?

This is a known issue with Mongo, it uses GUID values for the id if you do not specifiy your own. This also makes it difficult to do queries by id. the best solution to this is to always add your own numeric id values to the records as you insert them.

Your CustomerRepository is defined to use Long as the Id type. Just change it to String and you are golden.

_"Since mongoDB creates an id for me which is a String ..." - MongoDB creates the _id value (by default) of type ObjectId.

As Prasad mentioned, when MongoDB creates _id, it created the id of type Object ID.
Please refer to the documentation on ObjectId for reference.
Adding further, please follow the article on REST APIs with Java, Spring Boot, and MongoDB which would help you learn in performing CRUD operations with Spring Boot.
Please reach out in case you have further questions.
Regards
